# Loop for and variable type $u[s]

Tags: php, for-loop

I have loop for:

```
for($i=1; $i<6;$i++)
{
 echo ${'u'.$i};
}
?>
```

The variable $u was done in a loop: $u1, $u2 etc.

I need to do in the loop $u[s], the desired result: $u[s1], $u[s2] etc.
That does not work: ${'u[s'.$i.']'};

how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=1; $i<6;$i++){
    echo $u['s'.$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1; $i<6;$i++){
    echo $u["s{$i}"];
}
```

Comment: Please consider briefly explaining why this answer applies, so that others who see it will better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have A) a single array variable `u` with 5 keys, `s1` - `s5` OR do you have B) 5 variables, `u1` - `u5`?

If A), then use @Sudhir's answer.  I prefer the interpolation to the concatenation of @JOHN's answer.

If B), then do this:

```
for ( $i = 1 ; $i < 6 ; $i++ ) {

  $var_name = "u{$i}";

  echo $$var_name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable $u **should be** done in a loop this way: $u[1], $u[2] etc.

and so you'll be able to do

```
foreach($u as $var) {
  echo $var;
}
```

this is called `array` and the only proper way of handling enumerated variables